# Automatically Run a bash script when folder opens in windows on a USB drive

Tags: c++, windows, shell, filesystems, hook

I want to create a automatic log file whenever the folder opens in the USB.
In windows how to run a script when a folder is double clicked or opened from USB Drive.

like this autorun.sh